# Show the spectral radius of a matrix is smaller than 1

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues

Let $\hat{\bf H}$ be a $p\hat{N}\times p \hat{N}$ sparse matrix consisting of $p\times p$ blocks, where each block is of size $\hat{N}\times\hat{N}$. The values in $\hat{\bf H}$ is illustrated below (empty places are zero):

> [image]

The infinite norm of $\hat{\bf H}$ is obviously 1, and I know spectral radius is no larger than any natural norm. My question is how do I prove the spectral radius of this matrix is smaller than 1?

I did a simple numerical experiment, and found the claim should hold. If $p \to \infty$ and $\hat{N} \to \infty$, then the spectral radius should approach to 1.

If we fix $p = 5$ and let $\hat{N}$ go from 5 to 100, we have

> [image]

If we fix $\hat{N} = 10$ and let $p$ go from 5 to 100, we have

> [image]

Comment: $\lambda I - H$ is diagonally dominant for $|\lambda| \geq 1$.

Comment: Imagine a (complex) eigenvector with absolute value of eigenvalue equal to 1. Consider the coordinate with maximal absolute value. Get new coordinates with the same absolute value. Proceed. Also look for general statements, keywords should be Perron - Frobenius theorem and recursive Markov chain.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni but not strictly

Comment: @FedorPetrov Irreducibility considerations can be used to relax the strictness requirement (and the proof I know is exactly the one that you sketch). See e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weakly_chained_diagonally_dominant_matrix).

Comment: In simple terms, this matrix is conjugate to a block diagonal matrix with tridiagonal blocks (with each block having 0’s on the diagonal) so that each block is irreducible and sub-stochastic. Hence the spectral radius is the maximum of the spectral radius of the blocks, which are all strictly less than 1.

Comment: @AnthonyQuas Thanks for your help Anthony! I have some questions to consult you. The first one is by conjugate do you mean this matrix  similar to a block tridiagonal matrix? The second question is how we can get this block tridiagonal matrix? Thanks again for you help!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershgorin_circle_theorem